# Use existing database without creating it through models in play framework

Tags: playframework, ebean

So i have my database that is already made and i want to create an application in play framework that use the existing data from existing database and display it on my view

I studied that the default ebean present in play framework creates a database through the field defined in class? But if i want to use this existing database without recreating it.

Is it possible?
Can anybody help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to disable the evolutions plugins, go to your `conf/application.conf` file and uncomment (or add) line:

```
evolutionplugin=disabled
```

Of course you will need to write models which represents your DB tables to use Ebean anyway.